# changing compiler library standards on ubuntu

Tags: c++11

I am compiling one code repository which has a makefile,

```
make INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local install
```

and I get the following error:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
>   standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or
>   -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

How can I enable ISO C++ 2011 standard?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try -std=c++11 option?

Comment: actually, I am using GNU make. I use this command: make INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give any details on the code repository, does it use just a standard makefile, autotools, cmake ?

You may be able to just do a export CPPFLAGS="-std=c++11" prior to building building the code.

Comment: It uses a standard makefile

Comment: I have used your suggestion, but still, I get the same error. :/

Comment: looking at the repo, in graehl/graehl.mk, -std=c++11 is already set in ARCH_FLAGS, so should be used when compiling - what is the actual error is shows and where within the make procress?

Comment: yep - isn't using the std option - it is the master branch from git? In graeh;/graehl.mk, is there a ARCH_FLAGS= setting ?

Comment: I guess there is a different problem now :) http://pastebin.com/VbsfFbG4

Comment: Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: it cant find libz - maybe that  you don't have the libz devel files installed, or they are in a place it is currently not looking for them at.  the command 'locate libz' may help see if it had them installed somewhere else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120703/discussion-between-yusuf-and-lostbard).